# Есть метод setPosition для Actor'a, а есть ли getPosition? или как его создать?

Tags: android, libgdx

Мне нужен метод, который бы получал координаты Актёра.

Он существует по-дефолту или его нужно создать? Если создать, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, есть. Это getX() и getY(). Какой же я невнимательный.